# Scrapy & MySQL database:

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a website with Scrapy and store the information to a MySQL database.

My spider works on it's own. When I use it alongside a pipeline I get two errors

1. > [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2. > TypeError: connect() argument 1 must be string, not None

I'm new to python and scrapy.

Here is my Spider:

```
from scrapy import Spider
#from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scraper.items import ExpertScraperItem

class expertSpider(Spider):

    name = 'expert'

    start_urls = [
            'https://www.expert.ie/products/home-appliances/laundry',

            ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # follow links to product pages
        for href in response.css('a.product-list-link::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_product)

        # follow pagination links
        for href in response.css('a.UnselectedPage::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse)


    def parse_product(self, response):
        def extract_with_css(query):
            return response.css(query).extract_first().strip()


        item = ExpertScraperItem()

        item['model'] = extract_with_css('header strong::text')[12:100].strip()
        item['price'] = extract_with_css('span.TotalPrice::text')[1:100].strip()

        yield item
```

Here is my pipeline (this has been updated to show errors corrected 21/01/2018)

```
import scrapy
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi

class ScraperPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, dbpool):
       self.dbpool = dbpool

    @classmethod
    def from_settings(cls, settings):
       dbargs = dict(
          host = settings['MYSQL_HOST'],
      db = settings['MYSQL_DBNAME'],
      port = settings['MYSQL_PORT'],
      user = settings['MYSQL_USER'],
      passwd = settings['MYSQL_PASSWD'],
          charset = 'utf8',
          cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
          use_unicode = True,
        )
       dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb', **dbargs)
       return cls(dbpool)

        #pipeline the default call
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        d = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._do_upinsert, item, spider)  
        return item
    #Each row is updated or written to the database
    def _do_upinsert(self, conn, item, spider):                 

        valid = True
        for data in item:
            if not data:
                valid = False
                # raise DropItem("Missing {0}!".format(data))
                # print "Missing data"
        if valid:
            result = conn.execute("""
                insert into pricing(model, price) 
                values(%s, %s)
                """, (item['model'], item['price']))
            if result:
                print "added a model into db"
            else:
                print "failed insert into pricing"
```

Comment: can you post the entire stack trace, it's difficult to say where exactly that errors stems from without it

Comment: It is a lot more common to use a dict literal `{'host': 'localhost', 'db': 'database'}` then the `dict` construction you have in `from_settings` in your pipeline.

Comment: Also, what's going on with your settings? It seems like `settings['host']` should be `'localhost'`. `settings['localhost']` doesn't make much sense to me. What is the setting `'localhost'`?

Comment: I'd consider using SQAlchemy instead of MySQLdb. [Here](https://github.com/Amertz08/zillow_scraper) is a scrapy project I did that uses it

Comment: Hi everyone. Thanks a million for the help, there were two issues with my pipeline code: 1. The database settings weren't pointing to the information in the settings module. When fixed that now looks like this: @classmethod
    def from_settings(cls, settings):
    dbargs = dict(
    host = settings['MYSQL_HOST'],
    db = settings['MYSQL_DBNAME'],
    port = settings['MYSQL_PORT'],
    user = settings['MYSQL_USER'],
    passwd = settings['MYSQL_PASSWD'],
    charset = 'utf8',
    cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
    use_unicode = True,
  )

And the con.execute()

Comment: should've looked like this: 
result = conn.execute("""
                insert into expert(model, price) 
                values(%s, %s)
                """, (item['model'], item['price']))

Comment: Don't over complicate thing. You can do all inserts and updates inside pipelines